# Gettting row and colums from one left mouse click on QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm showing multiple images in a `QTableView`. Now I want to trace the image on which the user is pressing the left mouse button once, I want to trace it because I will show that exactly that image in a bigger window. How can I do that? I mean how I can get the row and column index of the image on which the user pressed the left mouse button once?

I cannot see any direct `clicked()` SIGNAL in QTableView, so what is the tool that gives me the row or column of the QTableView?

EDIT:
I thought I should also mention that I used `QStandardItemModel` to set the model in the `QTableView`. First I set the rows and colums of the model and then input each `QImage` type item(I convert the `QImage` to `QIcon`) in a `QStandardItem` and then put that `QStandardItem` in the `QStandardItemModel`, once the `QStandardItemModel` is setup or filled up I put in the `QTableView`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to obtain the pressed item's row and column values you need to connect your `QTableView`'s `pressed()` signal to a slot. Something like this:

```
connect(tableView, SIGNAL(pressed(const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT(onItemPressed(const QModelIndex &));
```

Here is the slot that will handle the mouse action:

```
void MyClass::onItemPressed(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    int row = index.row();
    int column = index.column();
    [..]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps to detect the single selected item, could you suggest something for selecting multiple Item?

Comment: @the_naive, take a look at `QAbstractItemView::selectedIndexes()` function. It will return the list of currently selected items.